# Navigation error with react native latest version 0.61.4

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

```
I upgraded my old project in react native version(0.61.4) then getting error related navigation option undefined.
```

Old project dependency version:--
      "react": "16.8.3",
      "react-native": "0.59.5", 
      "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.3",
New Project dependency versions:--
     "react": "16.9.0",
     "react-native": "0.61.4",
     "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
     "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    Note:-- I also tried with navigation version 2, 3.
    please help

[image: code image]

[image: error image]

Comment: You have used Drawer in react-navigation before?

Comment: Yes used react-native-scaling-drawer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the jump from react-navigation v1 to v4.

Check the `createNavigator` params

In v4 you should have a navigationConfig param passed like this:

`createNavigator(NavigationView, router, navigationConfig);`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html#createnavigator

If still not working probably you should check the breaking changes from here

https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/05/07/react-navigation-2.0.html

and also from v3 and v4.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Florin's answer, make sure you export wrap your root navigator with `appContainer`.

Docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html